# How do I get to etc/nginx on Alpine Linux server version 3.11?

Tags: nginx, alpine-linux

I ran `cd /`, then `cd etc/`, but I cannot find `nginx` in there. I also tried `etc/init.d/`, but that one is empty.

Comment: first question: is nginx installed? (Doesn't sound like it!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using the `find` command?
Run something like `sudo find / -name "*ngnix*"`.

This way you will scan the whole file system for what you are looking for.

Comment: this should probably be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @MarcusMüller, yeah unless he removes that question.

Comment: not really, to be honest. Nginx on alpine 3.11 (`apk add nginx`), I just tried, installs its config files to /etc. So, if that's not there, I think you might have more of an underlying problem.